# Intent.ACTION_DIAL skips the + on International numbers on some phones

Tags: android

On some phones when I create a Dial intent, like shown in the code below, with an international number starting with a plus, when the phone number reaches the dialer app of choice the plus is missing. While on others it works as intended. As an example it works on a OnePlus, it doesn't on a samsung.

```
String number = "+23454568678";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
startActivity(intent);
```

I could of course replace the plus with dubble zeroes, but I'd like to know if anyone has had this problem before. Haven't found anything here on SO, but maybe I'm not phrasing the problem correctly.

Is the a way to fix this, or does the problem lie with the dialer app which in turn might parse the number and remove the plus?

Comment: I can confirm it happens for us with Samsung devices as well, but works well on other devices

Comment: A quick update. I opened a ticket with Samsung. They identified the issue and it should be fixed in the next update on July. Once I'll verify it was fixed, I'll post it here as well.

Comment: I can confirm the issue have been fixed by Samsung on July 2021. Full details can be found in my answer below

Answer (score 1):

Samsung have approved this is a bug, and have fixed it in an OS update on July 2021.

I can confirm it fixed the issue we encountered with Samsung devices in our app, which was identical to the one presented in the question.

At least for device Samsung A51 the version that fixed the issue is A515FXXU4EUD7.

Based on the [RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3966#section-5.1.4) it is always better to add the + sign for international numbers

> Globally unique numbers are identified by the leading "+" character.
> Global numbers MUST be composed with the country (CC) and national
> (NSN) numbers as specified in E.123 [E.123] and E.164 [E.164].
> Globally unique numbers are unambiguous everywhere in the world and
> SHOULD be used.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    String phone = "+23454568678";
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.fromParts("tel", phone, null));
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Why would that work instead of my code above?

Comment: it makes sure the uri is well formed before passing it to the intent

Comment: @nheimann1 if I remember correctly I solved it by converting any plus I found to double zeroes.

Comment: @just_user Thank you. I'll just note for others that by the RFC, it should include the + sign, by https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3966. Section 5.1.4. Global Numbers.